# Line breaks are selectively ignored?

Tags: c, string

When I use `scanf("%[0-9a-z]",str);` str accepts a string of `0-9` or `a-z`. If the first character is a newline character, str should be an empty string. But `scanf("%[0-9a-z],%d",str,&d);` In this case, the first character is a newline character, but str is not an empty string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    char *str ;
    int d;
    scanf("%[0-9a-z]",str);
    // scanf("%[0-9a-z],%d",str,&d);
    printf("str = %s",str);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile the above code into a test executable file. When I enter `./test` and press a newline character to run, the program will run to the end and output `str=(null)`. It should be the beginning newline character, which ends the assignment of str. But when I commented the fifth line and uncommented the sixth line, then enter `./test` and press a newline character to run. It will enter the assignment state, enter `3 4`. At this time, the output str=3. Why in this case, the first newline character does not end the assignment of str?

Comment: What I want to know is the result of comparing these two situations. Why in the second case, I don’t need to allocate memory, while the first case requires？

Comment: I only asked one question. It is why one of these two cases can be assigned normally, and the other cannot. Is the comment just questioning its answer?

Comment: Change `char *str ;` to `char str[1000];`. Then, if the behavior you want to ask about persists, edit the code in the question so that it shows the case you are asking about (show the actual code with the problem, not different code along with instructions to comment and uncomment lines) and show the exact output in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory for `str`.

At the moment, with `char *str`, you've just defined a pointer to a C string.

When you scan, your characters are written to the random/garbage memory address in `str`. This may 'work' by luck sometimes, may lead to a program crash, or result in other undefined/weird results.

If you absolutely know the maximum length (e.g. 99 characters) of your string you can do:

```
char str[100];
```

You must always make the size one more for the null character.

Alternatively you can allocate memory:

```
char *str;

...

str = malloc(100);
```

Comment: An answer like this is better posted as a comment

Comment: But in the second case, why scanf("%[0-9a-z],%d",str,&d); can be assigned normally

Comment: @klutt I know. I've added details.

Comment: What I want to know is the result of comparing these two situations. Why in the second case, I don’t need to allocate memory, while the first case requires？

Comment: @cyj: You must always allocate memory. Defining an array `char str[100];` allocates memory because that is built into the definition of the array: The memory is allocated when the program starts (for arrays with static storage duration) or (approximately) when execution reaches the declaration (for arrays with automatic storage duration). Defining a pointer with `char *str;` allocates memory only for a pointer, not for anything it points to. So then you have to allocate memory some other way, such as by calling `malloc`.

Comment: But in the second case, I did not allocate memory. It can output the correct str value.